# Como recarregar página caso usuario tenha voltado no historico do browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um problema, que quando o usuário clica no botão de voltar no menu do browser, ele vai para a página anterior, mas a mesma não recarrega e mantem o conteúdo antigo. Como posso para recarregá-la quando esse evento acontecer ?

Comment: Você pode tentar escutar pelo evento popstate e verificar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta para a pergunta.
Quando o objeto "window.performance.navigation.type" for igual a 2, quer dizer que o usuário veio de uma página posterior pelo histórico do browser.

```js
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2) {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Não existe nenhum evento que detecta se o usuário clicou no botão de voltar na história do navegador, sendo assim acredito que a melhor maneira é trabalhar com `SESSION`.

Ao acessar uma página, você preenche uma `SESSION`, caso o usuário volte a visitar essa página você verifica a `SESSION`, se ele já acessou você pode usar: `location.reload();`

Não sei que linguagem você está usando mas em C# para chamar o script no back-end você pode utilizar o seguinte código: 
`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "reloadPage", "location.reload();", true);`

Comment: Nossa cara que gambiarra, sai fora.

Comment: Gambiarras movem o mundo, se tu conseguir resolver isso sem uma gambiarra mostra, valeu.